# How do I add a notification badge to a WPF app icon so that it appears in all places the app icon appears, not just the window title bar?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app which has an icon `AutoPBW.ico`. Now if I use this code in my MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
if (hosting && playerReady)
    Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("AutoPBW-hosting-playerReady.ico", UriKind.Relative));
else if (hosting)
    Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("AutoPBW-hosting.ico", UriKind.Relative));
else if (playerReady)
    Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("AutoPBW-playerReady.ico", UriKind.Relative));
else
    Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("AutoPBW.ico", UriKind.Relative));
```

I can make one of two badges appear, or both, or none, by replacing the icon with one of three alternate icons, or the original icon.

My problem is: if I do this, the icon only changes in the title bar of my window; it does not change in the taskbar, or in the notification tray (using the Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification library to make a notification tray icon appear). How do I change the icon for my app in all locations, not just in the title bar of the window?

Comment: For taskbar notification you can use [TaskbarItemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo?view=netframework-4.8) class

Comment: I see that `TaskbarItemInfo` has an `Overlay` property - I'd need to set this in addition to changing the icon of the form (by loading a whole new icon)? That sounds messy, changing the icon in two places using two different API paradigms (replace icon vs. add badge to existing icon)... is there a way to change both icons at once?